# Solution to exponential equation

Tags: exponential-function

I am trying to solve an equation for the ratio of a logistic model to an exponential model.

$$f(x)=2064.79\times(1.00089)^x$$
$$g(x)=\frac{134.664}{1+19.8553\times e^{-0.009944x}}+2754.48$$

Then how does one analytically solve the equation $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=2$?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Consider some numerical method. No analytical solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your help is valuable.

Comment: Numerically, no problem at all.